# Rate limiting after 206 requests - Uber API

Tags: uber-api

I am getting a 429 error after around 200 requests in 30 minutes.

The rate limit in the documentation is 2000/h and 500/s.

The endpoint that I am using is requests/getEstimate .

I am using the access token from the developer console.

Any idea why I am getting a 429 after 200 requests?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned there are couple rate limits:

- 2000 requests / hr for server tokens
- 2000 requests / hr for bearer tokens
- 500 requests / second short term rate limit per app

What you try to do is not usual behavior - you are trying to call requests/estimates endpoint 200 times in 30 minutes - so there is the additional limit for that endpoint that stops any overloading of the API calls.
Why will you need to call requests/estimates for a specific user (bearer token) more than 100/hour?
If you are trying to test API endpoint - you are getting a valid response. 
So please try to not go over 100/hour for requests/getEstimate endpoint and you will be safe.

Comment: As Sasa mentions, there are endpoint specific rate limits as well. We will work on better documentation for those. For requests/getEstimate, that is designed as an endpoint to be used with a user's bearer token, and there is not any reason to make over 100 calls in an hour for one specific user to that endpoint. Hope that helps!